# Deny direct access to folder from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So I have tried to follow some of the posts here to deny access to a public folder using .htaccess.
The problem is that I still can access the folder.

I have put the .htaccess inside my folder, with the commands?

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

I am missing something, but don`t know what.

BTW, I have restarted apache after that.

The site:

```
www.mysite.com
```

Folder I want to block

```
www.mysite.com/helloworld/
```

Comment: If you do not want that folders content to be publish, then why do you publish it in the first place? So why do you put it _inside_ the tree of folders accessible via requests?

Comment: No need to restart an http server if you are using `.htaccess` style files. However their interpretation must be enabled, otherwise they are simply ignored.

Comment: Good question. Is just to temporarily block it, I will remove it later, but right now I cannot

Comment: 1. Which apache version? 2. Is `AllowOverride` option provided in server config? 3. ^ what @arkascha said! PS: You do not need to restart apache to test changes made to htaccess file.

Comment: A general note: if you have access to the http servers configuration, then you should always prefer to place such configurations in there instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and _really_ slow the server down for nothing. They only serve as last option for those using a really cheap web space that does not offer any configuration access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That configuration does exactly what you say it should do when I test it.

Presumably your server is configured not to respect `.htaccess` files.

You can change that by setting:

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig
```

… in your main configuration file.

See also [the documentation for AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

---

That said, if you don't want the content of a directory to be accessible to anyone over HTTP, then you are better off keeping that directory outside the web root in the first place.